# iPhone Symbolicated Crash Log Analysis, ASIHTTPRequest involved

Tags: iphone, crash, crash-reports

I keep getting app rejected because of a crash that I can't never try to reproduce.

As a last chance, I am posting this crash log here, to see if there is someone out there who can dig out some useful info from it.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         Reeplay.it [3543]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/070AB7B3-E00D-4E96-97B9-AD35DF54339B/Reeplay.it.app/Reeplay.it
Identifier:      Reeplay.it
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-12-21 11:08:04.650 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33be9d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bdba20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347c594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347b4c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  Foundation                      0x33639910 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 648
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33a767d6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33a484f4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 188
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47e54 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
15  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
16  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
17  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 GSEventRun + 56
18  UIKit                           0x32099322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
19  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
20  Reeplay.it                      0x00002be4 main (main.m:14)
21  Reeplay.it                      0x00002b98 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d294 semaphore_signal_trap + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8b026 semaphore_signal + 2
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f258 pthread_mutex_unlock + 184
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347a5b8 objc_sync_exit + 44
4   Foundation                      0x33630782 -[NSThread _nq:] + 586
5   Foundation                      0x336303f4 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 724
6   Foundation                      0x3363007a -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 94
7   Reeplay.it                      0x00027c0c -[ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:1565)
8   Reeplay.it                      0x00035838 -[ASIHTTPRequest handleStreamComplete] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:2681)
9   Reeplay.it                      0x00026f1c -[ASIHTTPRequest handleNetworkEvent:] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:2462)
10  Reeplay.it                      0x0002a9ec ReadStreamClientCallBack (ASIHTTPRequest.m:52)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33a80f6a _signalEventSync + 70
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33a80efe _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 198
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33a767d6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33a485b0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
15  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47e54 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
17  CoreFoundation                  0x33a57efe CFRunLoopRun + 42
18  Reeplay.it                      0x00032528 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:3843)
19  Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
20  Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
21  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
22  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x336465f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0


Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8168c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a7f662 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd59f0 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8a7ec _pthread_cond_wait + 748
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8a3d2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                       0x31a41b14 WaitOnCondition + 4
4   CoreMedia                       0x31a41a5a FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 66
5   MediaToolbox                    0x300c0c9c fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                       0x31a5df76 figThreadMain + 166
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd59f0 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8a7ec _pthread_cond_wait + 748
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8a3d2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                       0x31a41b14 WaitOnCondition + 4
4   CoreMedia                       0x31a41a5a FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 66
5   MediaToolbox                    0x300c0c9c fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                       0x31a5df76 figThreadMain + 166
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a57efe CFRunLoopRun + 42
6   CoreMedia                       0x31a4c5c2 FigThreadGlobalNetworkBufferingRunloop + 86
7   CoreMedia                       0x31a5df76 figThreadMain + 166
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   MediaToolbox                    0x300c5d34 FigExpressNotificationThread + 36
3   CoreMedia                       0x31a5df76 figThreadMain + 166
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 10:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0
```

Here is the code corresponding to

7   Reeplay.it                       0x00027c0c -[ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:1565)

```
- (void)requestFinished
{
#if DEBUG_REQUEST_STATUS || DEBUG_THROTTLING
    NSLog(@"Request finished: %@",self);
#endif
    if ([self error] || [self mainRequest]) {
        return;
    }
    // Let the delegate know we are done
    if ([self didFinishSelector] && [[self delegate] respondsToSelector:[self didFinishSelector]]) {
line 1565 ------>[[self delegate] performSelectorOnMainThread:[self didFinishSelector] withObject:self waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];
    }

    // Let the queue know we are done
    if ([[self queue] respondsToSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)]) {
        [[self queue] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestFinished:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];       
    }

}
```

8   Reeplay.it                       0x00035838 -[ASIHTTPRequest handleStreamComplete] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:2681)

```
if (![self needsRedirect] && ![self authenticationNeeded]) {

        if (fileError) {
            [self failWithError:fileError];
        } else {
            [self requestFinished]; <------ line 2681
        }

        [self markAsFinished];

    // If request has asked delegate or ASIAuthenticationDialog for credentials
    }
```

9   Reeplay.it                       0x00026f1c -[ASIHTTPRequest handleNetworkEvent:] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:2462)

```
// Dispatch the stream events.
switch (type) {
case kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    [self handleBytesAvailable];
    break;

case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:
    [self handleStreamComplete];
    break;

case kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred:
    [self handleStreamError]; <------ line 2462
    break;

default:
    break;
```

}

Comment: Actually it's a problem by ASIHTTPREQUEST on iphone 1,2 with ios 3.1.3.
Recently our apps received a bunch of reports because of this.
I wonder anyone has a fix for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based the log, it seems that:

1. You assigned one of your ASIHTTPRequest to a ASINetworkQueue.
2. This request has finished, and is trying to notify its queue that it has finished. (Thread 3)
3. The queue says that it has implemented the **requestFinished:** selector and is happy to perform this selector on the mainthread.
4. The queue then tries to perform such a selector on the mainthread (thread 0). Then crash happens on thread 0.

I would suggest you go and check your implementation of **requestFinished:** of your queue class.

Best regards,

Di

Comment: actually I'm not using ASINetworkQueue, I'm just going through an array of urls, and I've implemented the requestFinished: method, that gets called fine.

What do you think could be that works here and doesn't at Apple Board?
I'm including all ASIHTTPRequest v1.7 files directly into the app.

Comment: I see. My ASI version may differ from yours. Can you show me the code near this line? **-[ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:1565)**

Comment: I've updated the question with some code relative to those lines into the log. There is an interesting "streamError", I should investigate this. Thank you again.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I seem to have the same problem.